# Use custom map style in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have successfully implemented Google Maps into my Xamarin Forms project but now I want to change its style. I want to use [a style from SnazzyMaps](https://snazzymaps.com/style/29/light-monochrome) but I don't know how to do that. I have read on the forums that you can load the json from SnazzyMaps into the application but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: [Video tutorial explaining how to customize Google Maps with SnazzyMaps, by Xamarin Guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OV1ChSc0S4Q)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your custom `Xamarin.Forms` GoogleMap renderer, you can set the style with the json content:

Xamarin.Android Example:

```
googleMap.SetMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.LoadRawResourceStyle(this, Resource.Raw.map_style_night));
```

Xamarin.iOS Example:

```
googleMapView.MapType = MapViewType.Normal; // Must be normal
var styleResource = NSBundle.MainBundle.GetUrlForResource("map_style_night", "json");
googleMapView.MapStyle = MapStyle.FromUrl(styleResource, null); // DO NOT pass an NSError, hard-crash / SIGSEGV
```

**Note**: Do **not** pass an `NSError` instance to `MapStyle.FromUrl` or `MapStyle.FromJson` with the current Xamarin.Google.iOS.Maps binding (`v2.1.0.2`) as this will cause a hard-crash (`SIGSEGV`). I had to create a custom binding to allow NSError as an `out` var in order to determine if the json is parsed correctly (also needed to the latest fixes in Google iOS Map `v2.4.30121.0` as Xamarin is binding/bundling the older `2.1.0.2` version).

[image]

Comment: I don't have a 'SetMapStyle' method

Comment: @Radu `SetMapStyle` is a method on the *native* Android GoogleMap class, you would need to use it within a custom renderer.

Comment: That's what I tried to do. I also tried to update all the nuget packages but the method still doesn't work

Comment: @Radu `Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap.SetMapStyle` (in `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps` package)

Comment: I marked your answer, but I need to wait 17 hours before giving you the bounty as well

Comment: Works. Maybe helpfull for style creating: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com

Answer (score 0):

Xaml:

```
     <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="1,10,0,0">
            <maps:Map        
                x:Name="MyMap" 
                IsShowingUser="true"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

I call this from code behind:

```
var assembly = typeof(MapPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.Helpers.Style.json");
            string Json = "";
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                Json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            MyMap.MapStyle = MapStyle.FromJson(Json);
```

Dont forget to put the .json as Embedded Resource.